# make UILabel roundrect shape

Tags: iphone

How to make `UIlabel`  roundRect shape ?
By changing background color of UILabel it looks like a rectangle in shape I want to make it look like a roundrect in shape.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more specific? A Label has no 'shape', it's a transparent area of text. Do you mean a UIButton?

Comment: @jv42 label is not necessarily transparent - you can set any background color to it like to any other uiview

Comment: @jv42 if u change background color of UILabel it looks like a rectangle in shape I want to make it look like a roundrect in shape.

Comment: @Vladimir: I was simplifying a bit...

Comment: you could edit your question with this information then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first import file

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

and than set the property of UIlabel as

```
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = kCornerRadius;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you mean to give the label a rounded-rectangle border, you can do that by setting the `cornerRadius`, `borderWidth`, and `borderColor` properties of the label's layer.

Comment: please explain how to use these properties

Comment: Look them up in the documentation, the info is all there.

Comment: @Gyani - you need to look into CALayer class for those properties